# Differentiating a Vector and a Matrix w.r.t. a Vector [Matrix Calculus]

Tags: matrix, derivative, calculus

I am studying matrix calculus for linear regression and machine learning and I would like to know exactly if the following calculations are correct:

Let $y=\sin(x+yz)$ and $r=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$

Then the following is the gradient of $y$ i.e., the derivative of $y$ with respect the vector $r$ in *denominator* layout: $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial\sin(x+yz)}{\partial r}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial \sin(x+yz)}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial\sin(x+yz)}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial \sin(x+yz}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(x+yz)\\z\cos(x+yz)\\y\cos(x+yz)\end{bmatrix}$$

In numerator layout it would be:

$$[\cos(x+yz), z\cos(x+yz), y\cos(x+yz)]$$

---

Now, let $$\mathbf{y}=\begin{bmatrix} e^{xyz}\\x^2z\\yx\end{bmatrix}$$

So in *numerator* layout: $$\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial r}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial e^{xyz}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial e^{xyz}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial e^{xyz}}{\partial z}\\ \frac{\partial x^2z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x^2z}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial x^2z}{\partial z}\\ \frac{\partial yx}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial yx}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial yx}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}\\ =\begin{bmatrix} yze^{xyz} & xze^{xyz} & xye^{xyz}\\2xz& 0 & x^2 \\y & x & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

In *denominator* layout it would be the transpose of the above matrix?

---

Now, let

$$Y=\begin{bmatrix} x^2yz & xy^2z \\xyz^2 & \ln(xyz) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} Y_{11} & Y_{12} \\Y_{21} & Y_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial r}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial Y_{11}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial Y_{12}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial Y_{11}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial Y_{12}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial Y_{11}}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial Y_{12}}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial Y_{21}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial Y_{22}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial Y_{21}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial Y_{22}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial Y_{21}}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial Y_{22}}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}$$

Would this be correct? I'm worrying I mixed up the shape and/or the positions of the members of the matrices $\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial r}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different [layout notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#/Layout_conventions) and each one is correct if used consistently. So, the first one is correct under *denominator* layout because the output dimension follows the denominator variable's dimension. The second one is correct in numerator layout. But, the third one is wrong because the derivative of a vector wrt a matrix and vice versa is a 3D tensor, not a matrix.

Comment: In this video (towards 6:30): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrH-jpJIqFQ , he says that it's a kronecker product between $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{ \partial }{\partial z}\right)$ and $Y$

Comment: It can be unrolled as kronecker product, bur essentially it’s a 3D tensor. This is like flattening a matrix.